# Marshall nested objects with jersey using entityfilter feature

Tags: java, rest, jersey, moxy

I'm using moxy withing glassfish 4.1 and have a working entityfilter configured to expose some attributes only on request.

Nested objects don't get marshaled when entityfilter feature is registered in my application.  When I disable entityfilter everything gets marshaled correctly.

If I delete all entityfilter annotations and just enable the feature, nested objects, which are deeper than level 2, don't get rendered.

Is there anything else to consider or enable when using entityfiltering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing additional to consider in terms of configuration, it is in fact a bug with the Jersey Entity Filtering Feature.

I ran into this same issue with my domain model and found your StackOverflow question and the Issue you posted on Jersey's Jira. I submitted some code to the Issue you raised on Jersey's Jira showing the bug and they have reopened the issue and added it to their backlog and will fix the bug in a future sprint.

https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2808

Comment: Thanks for your example. Good to know, that it wasn't a failure on my side :)

Comment: If this has answered your question, would you consider marking the question as answered?

Comment: Update from the ticket: "I'm sorry to say that but we do not plan to dedicate resources to fix this issue at the moment." - you got to be kidding me, as if the current behavior is at all acceptable ... MrTumnus did you manage to resolve the issue or provide a fix?

Comment: I turned off the Jersey Entity Filtering feature and use Jackson instead. Here's a link http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria